# Where is my syntax error in this SQL CHECK CONSTRAINT?

Tags: sql

I Apologize, but I have exposed my question to *google_and_ChatGPT*. I Think a need a ... human. Is my question so hard ?

To me, yes.

I have two colums in a Table in a SQL Server database.
I have checked that `(int)Logicial_Value` stays into `[0;2]` by

> Logical_Value BETWEEN 0 AND 2

I need to check if

> Int_Value < 5000 WHEN Logical_Value = 0

> Int_Value > 9999 WHEN Logical_Value = 2

(Gift : I let you guess what the Logical_Value = 1 should imply)

My Check Constraint Expression is :

```
CASE
WHEN Logical_Value = 0 THEN Int_Value < 5000
WHEN Logical_Value = 1 THEN Int_Value > 4999 AND Int_Value < 10000
WHEN Logical_Value = 2 THEN Int_Value > 9999
END
```

The hell, it doesn't work. It just allow any value for `Int_Value` at each case.
Note that SQL Server Management Studio throws an *Error Validating Constraint "foo"*.

My question is now why it let values (it cannot validate the constraint dear captain) but why it can't validate, and thus, **what is the correct syntax** ?

I'm feeling I have already RTFM, yes.

Comment: `CASE` does not work that way. The syntax is `CASE WHEN <boolean expression> THEN <value> ELSE <value> END`. Notably, boolean expressions in T-SQL are *only* allowed in specific contexts and nowhere else (there is no true independent boolean type), so you cannot use `CASE` to specify a condition here at all (unless you artificially compare to `1` or `0` or suchlike). You need to rewrite this using `AND` an `OR`, e.g. `(Logical_Value = 0 AND Int_Value < 5000) OR (Logical_Value = 1 AND ...)`.

Comment: You are not understanding the *case expression* - it returns a single scalar value, it does not perform control-of-flow or boolean logic.

Comment: Never (even in SQL dialects that support booleans) use `case` expression to calculate booleans based on some conditions (other booleans). It is much simpler, logically correct and readable to express this with boolean conditions and operators (and, or, not)

Comment: @astentx I would think that PostgreSQL behaves correctly with boolean predicates... in all combinations of CHECK and CASE, AND, OR, etc.

Comment: @TheImpaler No doubts, but what is the purpose to write `case` instead of `and` for booleans? If you want A and B to be true at the same time, then `A and B` is clear and works the same in every DBMS while `case when A then B end` does not. The only possible case may be to apply some conditions that will evaluate to error otherwise (for ex, `when data_type = 'int' then value = 5 when data_type = 'date' then value = date '1970-01-01' end`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rephrase your check constraint with a boolean predicate that doesn't return false for invalid combinations of values. For example:

```
check (logical_value = 0 and int_value < 5000
    or logical_value = 1 and int_value between 5000 and 9999
    or logical_value = 2 and int_value > 9999)
```

Comment: I always get nervous when `AND` an `OR` are mixed without parentheses to specify the precedence, even in cases where it happens to be correct. I've seen too many queries fail on someone accidentally adding a clause where it shouldn't have gone and wondering why they get back all or no rows.

Comment: @nbk I think it should work correclly. Is there any missing parenthesis?

Comment: Validated, while @JeroenMostert explanation feels like heaven !

Comment: @nbk no parens needed here, and looks very clean to me.

Comment: Parentheses clearly provide an original intent while missing parentheses do not allow you to distinguish between logical error and a requirement

Comment: @TheImpaler yes it is correct but with parenthesis it would be clearer and more understandable,

Comment: A software developer who can't understand the precedence here should get a new job.

Comment: More parentheses? This is SQL, not LISP.

Comment: Readability is all about how easy or difficult it is to read something.